# How add new tab on ribbon panel autocad 2009 C#?

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I found a lot of examples, how create new tab for AutoCAD 2010 - 2016. And nothing for 2009.
Ribbon panel appeared for the first time in AutoCAD 2009 and then it changed very much!
For example:

```
...
Autodesk.Windows.RibbonControl rbCtrl = ComponentManager.Ribbon; //doesn't work, coz ComponentManager is not exist in Autodesk.Windows
...
rbPanelSource.Items.Add(comboBox1); //doesn't work, coz Items has no Add method
...
/*Even example from ObjectARX 2009 doesn't work, coz haven't Ribbon in Autodesk.AutoCAD namespace*/
ribbonControl = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Ribbon.RibbonServices.RibbonPaletteSet.RibbonControl;
```

I does'nt understand, where i can find normal working examples or documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appologies, there's a little Ribbon API with 2009 SDK.
You have to reference the AcRibbon.dll and AdWindows.dll to be able to use :

```
var ribbonControl = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Ribbon.RibbonServices.RibbonPaletteSet.RibbonControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Ribbon .NET API is only available from the AutoCAD 2010 SDK.

Comment: Ok, then how can i create Tab on the top pannel in AutoCAD 2009 by C# ?